# timeIntervalSinceDate gives exc_bad_access or autorelease errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsdate, exc-bad-access

So I have an object which represents a line drawn on the iPhone screen.  I also have a ball moving around on the screen, and when the ball and the line intersect, the string is given a life.  For my current build I am receiving this error constantly, with no crashes, but the ball stops moving on the screen:

2011-08-18 11:00:05.436 myProgram[192:5e03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1531c0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

**Line.h:**
    @interface Line : NSObject {

```
//time properties
NSTimeInterval life;
NSDate *startTime;
NSDate *currentTime;
}



//time properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *startTime;


-(void) updateLife;

-(void) beginLifeTracking;

@end
```

**Line.m**

```
@synthesize startTime;

-(void)beginLifeTracking {
[self.startTime release]; //not sure if self is necessary here but startTime is released
                          //in case the same string is hit again
self.startTime = [NSDate date];
startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
//NSLog(@"Time Interval: %f",startTime);
}


-(void) updateLife {
currentTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
NSLog(@"breakpoint1");   
life = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
[currentTime release];
}
```

I'm assuming this is some sort of memory management error, but all my attempts to remedy it have failed.  I'd really appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: are you doing this on the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure that out, I haven't done anything to tell it to run on a specific thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `[self.startTime release]`, you're over-releasing. It's the job of the accessor (`setStartTime:`) to do this release.

The code doesn't make any sense, and is dangerous since it leaves a dangling ivar:

```
currentTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
NSLog(@"breakpoint1");   
life = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
[currentTime release];
```

This should be:

```
self.life = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
```

The fact that you're getting an autoreleasepool error suggests you're running this on a background thread. Your code is not thread-safe, so that would be a problem.

**EDIT** Regarding threading code, how are you calling `beginLifeTracking`? That would be where I would suspect you're getting onto the wrong thread. I would be very concerned about this autoreleasepool warning.

Comment: How would I go about figuring out if my code is thread-safe or fixing that problem.  Sorry, but this is something that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: I call it in a ball class instance where there is a collision.  In that class instance, when that ball collides with a line, the line is passed to another method to handle bouncing and I also call [line beginLifeTracking] as well as sound synthesis code for that line.  (when the life of the line ends, the sound stops).

Comment: Put a breakpoint here and see what thread you're on, and what the root of that thread is.

Comment: I'm on thread 1 for when I call beginLifeTracking, in beginLifeTracking, and in updateLife.  The root appears to be main (if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: It turns out that my problem is something different entirely, I figured a way to do this without bothering with NSDate at all, and I'm still getting the autorelease errors.  I have no idea what the source of my problem is yet, but as far as what I have posted goes, it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
```

Will overwrite the instance variable `startDate` with an autoreleased `NSDate`. Menaing the instance will be released and become a dangling pointer soon after the method has exited.

This is what causes your crash.

You method should probably look like this:

```
-(void)beginLifeTracking {
    self.startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    NSLog(@"Time Interval: %@", self.startTime);
}
```

I also uncommented your log statement and made it work.

Comment: Doing this throws the following errors on the first line of that method:

2011-08-18 11:49:20.228 myProgram[288:5e03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x16d0b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-08-18 11:49:20.207 myProgram[288:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d780'

Comment: `+dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` is a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: So I would call it as [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0] rather than the [[NSDate Date] dateWithTimeIntervalSince 1970] ?